# Ant Design how to handle Form.List accessing values from underlaying data structure?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, antd

I try to grasp `Form.List` [from Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item). I already figured out that it contains `FieldData[]`, where each element contains `name, key, fieldKey` but I do not know how to use this to access its values. I tried to solve the following two use cases based on a [code sample I found in another question](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-hill-vtb3f?file=/src/EditableUsersTable.tsx):

- Footer summing all ages to a total age for all users
- Adding sorters for age and name aka number and string columns

Condensed from the above [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-hill-vtb3f?file=/src/EditableUsersTable.tsx) example I have the following Form and Table code, leaving both TODO's which I'm not able to solve. Can you help me out?

If in general, you have knowledge about Form.List, this would also help a lot? For example explaining, why I need it for dynamic forms and what it is doing internally and for the component?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

```
import { Button, Form, Row, notification, Table, InputNumber } from "antd";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "antd/lib/form/util";

const TestForm: React.FC = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState({ users: [] });
 const [form] = useForm();
 const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState<number | undefined>(
   undefined
   );

 const onFinish = (values: any) => {
   notification.success({
       message: "Submit",
       description: `Received values of form: ${JSON.stringify(values)}`
   });
   setData(values);
   };

 return (
  <Form
  form={form}
  name="dynamic_form_item"
  onFinish={onFinish}
  initialValues={data}
  >
   <Form.List name="users">
    {(users, { add, remove }) => (
     <Table
      dataSource={users}
      pagination={false}
      footer={fields => {
       // TODO calculate age sum from fields
       return (
           <Button>Add User</Button>
       );
      }}
      >
       <Table.Column
           dataIndex={"age"}
           title={"Age"}
           width={125}
           sorter={() => {
             // TODO build something to sort here sorter: (a, b) => a.weight - b.weight,
             return 0;
           }}
           render={(value, row, index) => {
            return (
             <EditableFormItem
                 name={[index, "age"]}
                 editing={index === editingIndex}
                 className={"ant-form-item-no-bottom-margin"}
                 >
                 <InputNumber placeholder="age" min={0} max={150} />
             </EditableFormItem>
            );
           }}
       />
      </Table>
     )}
    </Form.List>
   </Form>
  )};

export default TestForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use the whole [NamePath](https://ant.design/components/form/#NamePath) to access the field's value.

- Your [<Form.List>](http://%20see%20https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List) has the name attribute `"users"`.
- When you map the `fields: Field[]` (in your case called `users`), ant maps each field's index to the `name` parameter.

Combine this information with the field's actual input name and you get the field [NamePath](https://ant.design/components/form/#NamePath) to access the form entry's value via `form.getFieldValue()`:

```
form.getFieldValue(["users", name, "age"])
```

Comment: I know we should avoid posting thanks in replies, but seriously you are a life saver. I have been adding the `name` of the `Form` instead of the `Form.List` and it returned `undefined` until I found your solution. Thank you so much really, I hope you are having a great day!